# How to customize this theme's ingredient amount/quantity?

Tags: wordpress

I purchased and installed [this theme](http://www.themeenergy.com/themes/wordpress/social-chef/recipe/a-delicious-summer-salad/) on Themeforest.

The author said that he was going to solve the issue in next upgrade of the theme about 1 month ago.

I do not want to wait for him so I need to do it on my own.

My problem is:
The amount of any ingredients ends with double digit ".00"
For example, if i type 6 grams, it looks like 6.00 grams and it's pretty annoying.

Do you have any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this "hack"

```
echo 6.00 + 0; // echos 6
```

Or do it the proper way and do this

```
$val = floatval(6.00);
```

Change this line

```
echo "<dt>" . $ingredient_result->amount . " $unit_name</dt>";
```

with this

```
echo "<dt>" . floatval($ingredient_result->amount) . " $unit_name</dt>";
```

Comment: Thank for the response. As you might guess, I'm a newbie so I did not get in which file I'm supposed to do that. Style.css?

Comment: No this is PHP, try to find something in functions.php / index.php / single.php / ... 
You can probably ask the theme developer about the function that manages that.

Comment: I found [those](http://i.imgur.com/YtIFFLh.png)in single-recipe.php yet cannot decide what to do. What should I do now, bro?

Comment: Edit your post and put the content of your file, i'll see if I can help.

Comment: Change this line
    echo "<dt>" . $ingredient_result->amount . " $unit_name</dt>";
with this

echo "<dt>" . floatval($ingredient_result->amount) . " $unit_name</dt>";

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed but ingredients sidebar crashed.

Comment: i'm guessing this is happening in many places in the template you need to look for the places where it talks about "amount"

Comment: Guess then I gotta wait for the update. Thank you very much anyway ;)